# .eq() out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to select the 3rd element of a JQuery object, by using eq() method. But for some reason the 2nd and 3rd selections pop out in changed order:

```
var selection = $("[name=input0], [name=input1], [name=input2], [name=input3]");
selection.eq(1); //turns out to be input2!!
```

What could be the reasons for this behavior? Can I trust acessing it by index in my script?

Comment: The order does not depend on the order they were selected, but instead on how they are held in the jQuery object, which in turn is determined by the order the elements appear in the DOM. As such, seeing your HTML would help here.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: According to JQuery Documentation, "To create a jQuery object with elements in a well-defined order and without sorting overhead, use the $(array_of_DOM_elements) signature."

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan indeed they are appearing in the DOM order (html), it's too big to put here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to:
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

The order of the DOM elements in the returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in document order.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the answers and comments and a bit of reading on the documentation.

Turns out that jQuery selects elements in the order they appear in the DOM (HTML), so:
Using a direct array access to a jQuery selection will work if you use that order, but you can only trust it if you are also responsible for the HTML, and you would need to remember this if you are ever going to change the layout.

**Bottom line**: not the best way to select a specific element.